# Different Tx/Rx rates of connected devices to my WiFi Router

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, home-networking

The wireless devices connected to my Wifi router have different Tx/Rx rate. For example, the Tx rates of two devices are 780 and 54 Mbps. I am curious about what causes these differences. Are these differences caused by the quality of hardware in these devices or some other factors? The wireless device with Tx rate of 780 Mbps, which is a iPhone 11 pro, gives me the idea that because it is new and expensive, it has greater Tx rate! Moreover, another device (Oneplus 7T phone) which is in the same distance from the router as iPhone 11 pro, has a Tx rate of 260 Mbps!

[The List of Connected Devices To My WiFi Router](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5ogS8.jpg)

Comment: Throughput rates have zero to do w/ how expensive a device is & everything to do w/ the WiFi radio & antennas within the device & router (WiFi radios are relatively inexpensive), coupled w/ the drivers for each. It's common to see a device have differing Tx/Rx rates between the device & router, w/ it being dependent on what the device is doing at that point in time. iPhones appear to only use a 20MHz bandwidth for the Rx link, which could explain the 6mbit/s, as each bandwidth step down halves throughput (i.e. going from 80MHz → 40MHz halves max throughput, while 80MHz → 20MHz quarters it).

Answer (score 0):

Devices will sometimes select a lower transmission rate based on the quality of the connection (or to save power), but ultimately the quality of the connection has many factors, the 3 most important are:

- the wireless standard used
- the frequency used
- the distance between the router and the device

If you can't move the devices closer to the access point (router), you can ensure that your router is configured to use the newest wireless standard that your device supports. An example of this would be to switch your router from b/g/n mode to just n mode.

From your screenshot, some of your devices connected using a frequency of 2.4 Ghz, instead of your router's faster frequency: 5 Ghz. Try to connect that device your router on the 5 Ghz network **Note: Some devices only have 2.4 Ghz available, and are unable to connect on 5 Ghz.**

**Tip:** Sometimes you may have to give your 2.4 Ghz network and your 5 Ghz network different names (SSID's) in your router's configuration in order for you to connect your devices to the faster network.

Refer to this table for the maximum speeds you can expect based on the wireless standard and frequency.

```
| Standard | Frequency | Theoretical Speed   |
|----------|-----------|---------------------|
| 802.11b  | 2.4Ghz    | 11 Mbps             |
| 802.11g  | 2.4Ghz    | 54 Mbps             |
| 802.11n  | 2.4Ghz    | 300 Mpbs            |
| 802.11n  | 5Ghz      | 900 Mbps            |
| 802.11a  | 5Ghz      | 6-54 Mbps           |
| 802.11ac | 5Ghz      | 433 Mbps - 1.7 Gbps |
```

Table source: [CenturyLink Wifi Info](https://www.centurylink.com/home/help/internet/wireless/which-frequency-should-you-use.html)

That being said, your Tx and Rx rate will be capped at whatever rate you purchase from your ISP, for example, you could have a Tx of 300 to your router but if you only have 100 from your ISP, 100 will be the maximum speed achieved to online servers.

Comment: You forgot the simplest deciding factor: number of spatial streams. Many phones are 1x1 while many laptops are 2x2.

Comment: It's true, certain devices will have lower maximum transfer rates due to the number of stream they use. A single stream (1x1) on the Wireless N standard would do 150Mbps. You would add 150 for each additional stream: dual stream (2x2) giving 300Mbps and three streams (3x3) offering speeds of 450Mbps.

Comment: Regarding the last paragraph, ISP rates have zero to do with the Tx/Rx rates shown, as they're between the device and the router, not the device and the ISP _(the latter's throughput would be garnished via a speed test)_. Legacy rates should always be disabled unless there's a device with a b/g radio connecting to the network and WiFi radios should always have a specific channel set and never be left on Auto, preferably a DFS channel _(2.4GHz: `1`, `6`, or `11` and 5GHz: highest available, although in the US, channel `157` works best on a 80MHz bandwidth [160MHz only has 2 DFS channels])_

Comment: Are you sure that is correct about 11n on 5GHz being able to do 900mbps? I think 11n on 2.4GHz and 5GHz have the same bitrate capability. 900mbps would be 6 bonded channels, which is something that 11ac can do.

Comment: @JW0914 Does you have a source for the claim that legacy rates should be disabled? I believe the 11g preamble is fully compatible with the 11n one. 11b causes problems on 11g/n networks, but only when actually connected as far as I know. Overlapping channels between other networks is what really makes things unreliable.

Comment: @AlexCannon Google it, as having legacy rates enabled can result in slower throughput on many devices, which is why it's recommended [in general] to disable legacy rates entirely unless there's a legacy device that isn't N compatible

Comment: Some routers, like mine, don't have the option to disable legacy wi-fi modes. It's `b/g/n` only for the 2.4 Ghz band. Although from what I understand, the router doesn't operate with decreased performance unless a `b` or a `g` device is connected. See this answer for more details: https://superuser.com/a/626512/1144540

Comment: @iskyfire I did google it and came across this. https://divdyn.com/disable-lower-legacy-data-rates/ . It does make a big point about how having 11b enabled will force beaconing at 1mbps, when it may otherwise be able to do 6mb+ beacons which significantly shortens the airtime used, especially when many APs are sharing a channel. I haven't found any info about 11g mode reducing the performance of 11n. However, that article is meant for a large area where interference isn't an issue. Many home networks drop down to 1/2/5.5 because g modes CANNOT handle even narrow band interference.